# OpenLayers 6 highly frequent layer updates with large amounts of points

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl, openlayers

I'm currently using OpenLayers 6 in order to display geo data generated by a mobile mapping application. This includes a "live" GPS location that updates up to 10 times per second. I can run my application at this speed without any problems by updating the feature on the layer.

A second feature is having the GPS leave "breadcrumbs" behind on the map. These points are added 10 times per second to a specific layer. I've been using `WebGLPointsLayer` to display these points which massively increased performance to a solid 25.000 points before I'm running into issues. The points are added using the following code:

Layer initialisation:

```
this.gpsBreadcrumbsLayer = new WebGLPointsLayer({
    source: new Vector({}),
    style: {
        symbol: {
            symbolType: 'circle',
            size: 10,
            color: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)'
        }
   }
});
```

Adding a feature based on the received lonLat ([lon, lat])

```
const source = this.gpsBreadcrumbsLayer.getSource();
source.addFeature(new Feature(new Point(fromLonLat(lonLat))));
```

I'm looking for a high-performance solution that allows me to draw beyond ±25k points on the map without impacting the performance and responsiveness of the map. I've seen examples that easily handle ±250k points but these are loaded in once and these points aren't added dynamically at 10 times per second.

I'm also not sure how OpenLayers works under the hood, but it performance-wise it seems like OpenLayers is redrawing the entire layer when a feature is added as it gradually decreases performance over time. Whenever I stop adding points I'm seeing a performance return even with, the already generated points still on the map.

**TL;DR** I need a way to dynamically add 10 Points per second to a layer that can easily go up to 100.000 points without a noticeable performance impact. `WebGLPointsLayer` helps me out a lot but slows me down when hitting 20/25 thousand points.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a performance issue when drawing features on the map and solved it by first adding them to an array and then after all features are in the array add them all to the source. I'm guessing here but it might be a fair bit of overhead when adding every single feature one at a time and that is alleviated by adding them all at once.

```
// Array 
newFeatures.push(feature);
```

Then somewhere else add them all to th source at once.

```
vectorSource.addFeatures(newFeatures);
```

This helped out by allowing me to draw around 25 000 features with text from around 2 000.